# C# ScrapySharp 'System.Net.CookieException: 'The 'Name'='HttpOnly, NID' part of the cookie is invalid.'

Tags: c#, scrapysharp

So i'm facing an unexpected issue with my code. For some reason, I am unable to download & print the links out of my Google search... Help is much appreciated as I'm really not sure what is going on here... I am also using the DotNET SDK

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ScrapySharp;
using ScrapySharp.Extensions;
using ScrapySharp.Network;
using static System.Console;
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var query = "scrapysharp";
            Console.WriteLine($"Searching '{query}' on google");

            var browser = new ScrapingBrowser();
            browser.UseDefaultCookiesParser = false;
            var resultsPage = await browser.NavigateToPageAsync(new Uri($"https://www.google.fr/search?q={query}"));

            Console.WriteLine($"Results");

            foreach (var link in resultsPage.Html.CssSelect("h3.r a"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"- {link.InnerText}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
System.Net.CookieException: 'The 'Name'='HttpOnly, NID' part of the cookie is invalid.'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, the quick workaround for me was bellow one line code.

```
browser.IgnoreCookies = true;
```

Leave everything else as is, add this line after the line where you are creating browser object and try it out.